We couldn't reach this Repl Make sure this Repl has a port open and is ready to receive HTTP traffic
I ran into this error, while trying to launch my webview on replit. (some pythion code)

Hmm... We couldn't reach this Repl. Make sure this Repl has a port
open and is ready to receive HTTP traffic.

My external port is currently set to 3000. I'm a novice and don't really know what I'm doing wrong
I tried to run the app the webview and expected it to run

Try doing

kill 1 in your replit shell and rerun the code
Shorten the name of your repl, sometimes the issue is the lengthy name


Do these:

Try kill 1 in your repl's shell. This restarts the repl.
Make sure the code is running while you open the webview URL.
Make sure you have set the right internal port. If you want help reply with link to your replit code and I'll check it.
Make sure your .dev URL has the port 3000. ([URL] :3000)
Try the webview in the Replit interface. Click the new tab (+) button where it says the open files` names on the top of the interface and search for webview. If the webview in Replit interface works, then copy the link above the webview page and paste it into the address bar.

